# How to refer to other sheet in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

i can access the current sheet using :

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

But how to access other sheets from the same spreadsheet file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to get sheets in a spreadsheet:

- Get them by their name: [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname)
- Retrieve all of them in an array: [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)

Answer (score 1):

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
```

In between quotes, enter the ID of the Spreadsheet you want to use.

How to get the ID of a spreadsheet? The red arrow in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X9wr.png) points to the spreadsheet id.